# What Prettier/ESLint setting is this

Tags: eslint, prettier

Prettier/ESLint is taking this line:

```
(contentType != null && contentType.indexOf('javascript') === -1)) {
```

and making it into this:

```
            if (
                response.status === 404 ||
                (contentType != null &&
                    contentType.indexOf('javascript') === -1)
            ) {
```

I'm using Webstorm, but the command line output is this:

```
$ eslint src

C:\Users\jtuzman\dev\...\front_end\src\serviceWorker.js
  109:40  error  Replace `·contentType.indexOf('javascript')·===·-1)` with `␍⏎····················contentType.indexOf('javascript')·===·-1)␍⏎············`  prettier/prettier

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
  1 error and 0 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.
```

I've done some customizing of the prettier config (including explicitly writing out defaults):

```
module.exports = {
    tabWidth: 4,
    tabs: false,
    semi: true,
    singleQuote: true,
    quoteProps: 'as-needed',
    trailingComma: 'none',
    bracketSpacing: true,
    jsxBracketSameLine: true,
    arrowParens: 'avoid'
};
```

But I can't tell what rule this is about. Perhaps it's an eslint rule. Anyone have ideas?